# In Dashcode, with iPhone webkit, how to add a new page?

Tags: iphone, webkit, web-applications

I'm working on a website for iphone using dashcode. But i don't know how to add a new html page to the 'site'. I could use stackLayout but it takes so much time to load the 'index.html' since it has all the stackLayout's views in it.

enlightenment needed :)

Answer (score 0):

rather than adding a new html page you could split the existing index.html into "pages" with each page in a  and then use the javascript to manipulate the visibility of the divs.

so the javascript looks like this

```
  function hide_me(el) { 
if(document.getElementById(el)) {
    if(document.getElementById(el).style.display != "none") 
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = "none";
}
```

}
  function show_me(el) {
    if(document.getElementById(el)) {
        if(document.getElementById(el).style.display == "none") 
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = "block"; 
        }
  }

then in the html

```
   <ul>
     <li><a href="javascript:
   show_me('one');
   hide_me('two');
   hide_me('three');
        etc......
     </li>
  </ul>
```

and further down the index.html

```
        <div class="mainContent" id="one">
        <!-- generated html -->
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="head">
                    <td class="item" colspan="2">
                        CHMOD
                    </td>
                </tr>
         etc .....
     </table>
     </div>
```

This way the load is all taken when the widget is fired up and therafter you just display the divs as opposed to having to load them

Comment: Hi ; if i want to do design for multiple pages using interfaces, how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Click:

> FILE > NEW > FILE

Then, rename the file to "whatever.html"

You're welcome!

My site was made with Dashcode!